# Using Baidu Map for react native/expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building a React Native App for a Chinese Company. I'm using Expo.

I really would love to use Google Maps, but it is not allowed there...

The best solution I found was to use Baidu Map,
I searched for SDKs and found some of them in GitHub.
I decided to use this one: https://github.com/qiuxiang/react-native-baidumap-sdk
which provides great documentation.

Although, I'm having some trouble implementing it to the app. I think that they don't support expo.

Does anyone here ever have a similar problem?
Or used another map...

Would really save my life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library uses native (Android & iOS) SDKs and provides a React Native API on top of them. Expo does not yet support custom native modules, which means you'll have to eject from it to use this package (or any other that uses BaiduMap or other native code).

I'm guessing they probably have a web based JS SDK instead which you could try to integrate into your app via a `<WebView />` instead?

Comment: Thank you very much!